# set->Flash not working when called from Jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm working on a CakePHP project, on a view I'm calling a method in the controller like this:

```
var addEnv = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'controller_method')) ?>";
$.post( addEnv, function(  ) {
     location.reload();
});
```

The controller method looks like this:

```
 public function controller_method()
    {
       if($this->request->is('post'))
       {   
            $this->someTable->set(array(
            'comments' => "PUM"
          ));
          $this->someTable->save();
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY', true), 'alert-success');
          return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit'));
       }
   }
```

The method works correctly and I'm redirected to the edit view, which is the behavior that I expect, but the message with DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY text is not displayed, the same setFlash method was used on another views successfully.

Why I cannot see the message on the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like controller_method() is rendering the view for `'action'=>'edit'` (by redirecting) and returning that as a response to $.post()

The rendering of the 'edit' view may be including your flash message, and then you are using javascript (the success callback in $.post) to reload the page. Since the 'edit' view already showed the flash message, it won't show it again after you reload the page.

You can inspect the $.post response to see if your flash message is in there. If this is the case, have the cake method respond without rendering a view. I think this will work:

```
public function controller_method()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->someTable->set(array(
          'comments' => "PUM"
        ));
        $this->someTable->save();
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY', true), 'alert-success');
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that without location.reload() the page is not updated, so I have to hit F5 to see the changes that I made, that's why I put it.

Comment: true, sorry, I just meant you should disable `location.reload()` in order to read the `console.log` message, which will allow you to see if the flash message was included. So instead of doing that you can replace the `redirect` line in cake with `$this->autoRender = false; return;` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot csum, it worked, the only thing to mention is that location.reload is needed on the .post call, you can edit that on your response. I appreciate your help.